# How should i insure all unique items are there in the unique items python list?

Tags: python, image

So I am sorting unique images and similar images by using python dhash library and during comparison of images I compare each image with it's 10 neighbors on both side of the current Image but my script deletes the all similar Images from unique list without keeping one Image from similar list to unique list, how can I solve this here is the code that i have written so far :

```
def compare_image(curr_img, curr_img_hash, to_compare):
    """
    Function for comparing two images

    """
    global norm_cache
    if to_compare in norm_cache:
        print(f"cached val found for {to_compare}")
        gray2 = norm_cache[to_compare]
        h2r,h2c =  dhash.dhash_row_col(gray2)
        hash2 = dhash.format_hex(h2r,h2c)
    else:
        print("No cached_val found, Computing and storing in norm_cache")
        gray2 = _get_image(to_compare)
        h2r,h2c =  dhash.dhash_row_col(gray2)
        hash2 = dhash.format_hex(h2r,h2c)
        norm_cache[to_compare] = gray2  # Update cache...

    print(f"Values ----> {curr_img} : {curr_img_hash}, {to_compare} : {hash2}")
    if distance.hamming(curr_img_hash,hash2) <= threshold:
        print("images are same")
        return "similar"
    else:
        print("images are different")
        return "different"


def find_duplicates(folder) -> tuple:
    """
    Main function to find duplicates.
    """
    uniques: list = list()
    similar: list = list()
    buffer:  list = list()
    
    
    image_list = os.listdir(folder)
    for image_index in range(0,len(image_list)):
        curr_img = image_list[image_index]
        full_path = os.path.join(folder, curr_img)
        gray1 = _get_image(full_path)
        h1r,h1c =  dhash.dhash_row_col(gray1)
        hash1 = dhash.format_hex(h1r,h1c)
        # compare left 10s
        x = image_index - 10
        if x < 0:
            x = 0
        if x < image_index:
            for prev_image_index in range(x, image_index):
                if os.path.isfile(full_path) and os.path.splitext(full_path)[-1] in image_exts:
                    prev_image = image_list[prev_image_index]
                    prev_full_path = os.path.join(folder,prev_image)
                    result = compare_image(curr_img, hash1,prev_full_path)
                    if result == 'similar':
                        if prev_full_path not in similar:
                            if prev_full_path not in buffer:
                                buffer.append(prev_full_path)
                            similar.append(prev_full_path)
                    if result == 'different':
                        if prev_full_path not in uniques:
                            uniques.append(prev_full_path) 
        #compare right 10s
        x = image_index + 10 + 1
        if x > len(image_list):
            x = len(image_list)
        if x > image_index:
            for j in range(image_index+1,x):
                if os.path.isfile(full_path) and os.path.splitext(full_path)[-1] in image_exts:
                    ahead = image_list[j]
                    ahead_full_path = os.path.join(folder,ahead)
                    result = compare_image(curr_img, hash1,ahead_full_path)
                    if result == 'similar':
                        if ahead_full_path not in similar:
                            similar.append(ahead_full_path)
                    if result == 'different':
                        if ahead_full_path not in uniques:
                            uniques.append(ahead_full_path) 

    for i in similar:
        if i in uniques and i in buffer:
            uniques.remove(i)

    print(f"{len(similar)} Similar Found...")
    print(f"{len(uniques)} Unique Found...")

    return similar, uniques
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass all elements to a python set, which automatically keeps only unique values. After that, you can sort your list by using sorted and convert it back to a list

```
mySet = {'a', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'b'}
myList = list(sorted(mySet))
```

Might not be the most efficient solution, but it does the work